# tensorflow.saved_model.load() takes extremely long time to execute

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following function to download, store and load models from the [tensorflow model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md):

```
def load_object_detection_model(model_name: str):

    models = load_model_zoo_list()
    model_url = models[model_name]['url']
    model_filename = models[model_name]['filename']

    pretrained_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "pretrained_models")
    os.makedirs(pretrained_path, exist_ok=True)

    get_file(fname=model_filename, origin=model_url, cache_dir=pretrained_path, cache_subdir='cptr', extract=True)

    loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load(os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'cptr', model_name, "saved_model"))

    return loaded_model

def load_model_zoo_list():
    """

    :return:
    """

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "model_zoo.json")
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        model_zoo_json = json.load(f)

    return model_zoo_json
```

**model_zoo.json**

```
{
  "ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8": {
    "url": "http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz",
    "filename": "ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz"
  }
}
```

The idea is tho simply add more models to the json later, `ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8` was simply chosen at the moment for testing.

The problem is the following. The line  `loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load(os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'cptr', model_name, "saved_model"))` takes around 25-30 seconds to execute. The model is already downloaded at this point and the `saved_model` folder has a size of around 32Mb. I also tested with bigger models, which took even longer. Inference seems to be much to slow as well (compared to the speeds listed on the model zoo page).

Apart from that, the model seems to work.

What could be the reason for these models being so slow?

Comment: just tested: With `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8` model and a image of size 256x256 pixels, I have a inference time of 22 seconds. The results look ok, but something is seriously wrong with the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! On the first model call, the graph is built, so the first call to the model is always slow. I tried your code on google colab using a GPU:

```
model = load_object_detection_model("ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8")
```

```
%%time
a= model(np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1, 320, 320, 3)).astype("uint8"))
```

CPU times: user 4.32 s, sys: 425 ms, total: 4.75 s
Wall time: 4.71 s

```
%%time
a= model(np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1, 320, 320, 3)).astype("uint8"))
```

CPU times: user 124 ms, sys: 18.4 ms, total: 143 ms
Wall time: 85.4 ms

In the document, they say 22 ms for this model, but maybe they got a faster GPU.

Comment: I get similar results with this model. With `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8` it still takes around 14 seconds per image after a few iterations... I will play around with other models and will mark this answer if no other comes around. The question remains, if one can speed up the graph building somehow. In my usecase, the user can choose a model from a list and start inferences, if every time the loading takes 20-30 sekonds, this becomes unfeasible

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might want to use *TFlite*. It's a tool for running TensorFlow models on mobile devices (but it also works on Linux). The models need to be converted, but this is well documented. Since the model will be much smaller, you can expect to have a lower load time